# Google Tag Manager - GTM Data layer problems

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've installed the GTM code on a HTML5 bootstrap 5 template, the GTM container and a analytics global site tag added to GTM appear to load and initialise the DOM fine within the GTM preview/debug.  The analytics tag pushes click data and the limited event data to the analytics console without issue.

The problem is with GTM variables.  In debug mode the loaded GTM container picks up scroll and page events and sets the associated variables but in the case of form data layer variables **it has set them once** while in debug/preview mode during a newsletter form submission, but doesn't seem to want to set them again in different later debug sessions.

The template in use is:

https://www.okler.net/previews/porto/9.1.0/demo-digital-agency-2-dark.html

The developer doesn't want to offer support for GTM or GA so I was wondering if anyone could see an issue with why the newsletter signup at the end of the page for example  that wouldn't set the form data layer variables as expected within GTM when filled and submitted.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that it pushes the dataLayer event only once per form submission and not more?

Is there a value of tracking multiple form submissions for one user?

If there is enough value to bother fixing it, you can just consider either finding how they prevent subsequent form tracking and fix it, or you can just have custom tracking in GTM. So that you would be able to detect CTA clicks.

But tracking CTA clicks instead of actual form submissions will lead to the opposite problem: too many CTA clicks.

Basically, you have to understand why you're tracking it. What question is to be answered here. In this case the obvious question is whether a user converted. To answer this question, you actually don't need subsequent submissions tracking.

If the question here is how many times the user submitted the form, then simple CTA tracking plus error tracking will suffice. It's not connected to form submissions tracking tho. Different questions - different answers.

Comment: GTM Debug shows no data layer variable values what so ever when the form is submitted.   The debug info goes as far as scroll depth then nothing more when the form is submitted.

Comment: It looks like the datalayer push is somehow being blocked?  There is no reason the Form variables shouldn't be set as all gtm.js gtm.dom gtm.load events are initialised on the debug panel, this assuming all the Form variables are activated, which they are.

Comment: seems like you think that dataLayer pushes are meant to be done with GTM. They're not. If you're seeing them, it's likely the FE devs/your FE framework is trying to make your life easier. Or you confuse GTM events with DL events. Different things. Anyhow, form tracking is something that is done on the FE, not in GTM. GTM can only give you some approximation of form submission. Unless it's a real html form submission, which it's not. They're deprecated.

Comment: But it's GTM that passes the DL event whatever it was originally called, subsequent trigger and tag to Analytics which is the purpose?  You're saying GTM and Analytics event data is just an approximation, ruling out ad blockers?

Comment: It had correctly fired once, I'll take the bug up with google.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, issues been referred to google.